# How to prove $(A\lor B)\rightarrow C\therefore (A\rightarrow C)\land(B\rightarrow C)$ is right in logic?

Tags: logic

I wrote down:

1. $(A\lor B)\rightarrow C$ (Premise）
2. $\neg\,(A\lor B)\lor C$
3. $\neg\,C\rightarrow(A\lor B)$
4. $\neg\,C\rightarrow(\neg\,A\land\neg\,B)$

I can't write anything more than these
Please help.
Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

The following should suffice:

0. $(A\lor B)\implies C$
1. $A$ $\qquad$ [assume]

   1.1. $A\lor B$ $\qquad$ [$\lor-$in]

   1.2. $C$ $\qquad$ [Follows from 0]
2. $A\implies C$
3. $B$ $\qquad$ [assume]

   3.1. $A\lor B$ $\qquad$ [$\lor-$in]

   3.2. $C$ $\qquad$ [Follows from 0]
4. $B\implies C$
5. $(A\implies C)\land (B\implies C)$ $\qquad$ [Follows from 2 & 4]